# TypeError: '(slice(0, 15, None), 15)' is an invalid key

Tags: python, pandas, csv, anaconda, slice

I have a code in Python that looks something like the code pasted below. For context, the all csv files print [15 rows x 16 columns], I just changed the name for privacy purposes.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 

C = pd.read_csv('/Users/name/Desktop/filename1.csv')
Chome = pd.read_csv('/Users/name/Desktop/filename2.csv')
Cwork = pd.read_csv('/Users/name/Desktop/filename3.csv')
Cschool = pd.read_csv('/Users/name/Desktop/filename4.csv')
Cother = pd.read_csv('/Users/name/Desktop/filename5.csv')

Cf = np.zeros([17,17])
Cf = C
Cf[0:15,16] = C[0:15,15]
Cf[16,0:15] = C[15,0:15] 
Cf[16,16] = C[15,15]

print(Cf)
```

When I run the code I get the following error:

```
runfile('/Users/name/.spyder-py3/untitled12.py', wdir='/Users/name/.spyder-py3')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/Users/name/.spyder-py3/untitled12.py", line 23, in <module>
    Cf[0:15,16] = C[0:15,15]

  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2800, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)

  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 2646, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(key)

  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 111, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc

  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 116, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc

TypeError: '(slice(0, 15, None), 15)' is an invalid key
```

I am not exactly sure what this error means. I am pretty new to python, so debugging is a skill I am trying to better understand. So any advice on what I can do to fix this error, or what it means would be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: `Cf = C ; Cf[0:15,16] = C[0:15,15]` You are overwriting the array `Cf` with the dataframe `C`, so `C[0:15,15]` does not make sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note the following sequence in your code sample:

```
C = pd.read_csv(...)
... # Other cases of pd.read_csv
Cf = np.zeros([17,17])
```

So, at least till now, *C* is a *DataFrame* and *Cf* is a *Numpy* array.

Then `Cf = C` is probably a logical error, since it overwrites
the *Numpy* array (full of zeroes) with another reference to *C*.

And now as the offending instruction (`Cf[0:15,16] = C[0:15,15]`) is concerned:

Note that `C[0:15,15]` is wrong (run this code on your own to see it).
In case of *pandasonic* DataFrames you can use "positional addressing",
including slices, using *iloc*.

On the other hand, this notation is **allowed** for *Numpy* arrays.

So, assuming that `Cf = C` is not needed and *Cf* should remain a
*Numpy* array, you probably should correct this instruction to:

```
Cf[0:15,16] = C.iloc[0:15,15]
```

And make analogous corrections in remaining instructions in your code.

## Edit

Another option is to refer to the underlying *Numpy* array in *C* DataFrame,
using *values* attribute.
In this case you can use *Numpythonic* addressing style, e.g.:

```
C.values[0:15,15]
```

causes no error.